# Technical term for "copy-catting nature"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

There is a term for copy-catting nature for practical situations such as cars, systems, etc. For example an engineering project where some part is designed according to bird wing. This methodology of using nature as a model for something has some technical name but I cannot remember it now. What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Biomimetics** is the study of the structure, function and processes of biological organisms and/or systems as models for the design and engineering of materials and machines. It is widely regarded as being synonymous with **biomimicry**, **biomimesis**, **biognosis** and similar to **biologically inspired design**.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biomimetics

Comment: how do you make an adjectives from the issue? Biomimetical or biomimetic? Apparently biomimetic after some googling, other?

Comment: *Biomimesis* is a noun meaning *the imitation of life*.  From this, we get the adjective *biomimetic* and the field of study *biomimetics*.